# Add class to an element without an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items:

```
<div class="crew-item>
     <div class="crew-grid"></div>
     <div class="crew-detail></div>
</div>
<div class="crew-item>
     <div class="crew-grid"></div>
     <div class="crew-detail></div>
</div>
<div class="crew-item>
     <div class="crew-grid"></div>
     <div class="crew-detail></div>
</div>
```

When I click on a selected 'crew-grid' I'd like to add a class ('active') to its 'crew-item' parent, but I have no idea how to achieve that using vanilla js or jQuery. 
The goal is to reveal the 'crew-detail' part, with active class added to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

```
$('.crew-grid').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.crew-item').addClass('active');
});
```

Basically, starting from the clicked element, get the closest ancestor element which matches that selector.  You don't need an `id` to target an element, just a way to identify it based on the information you have (in this case the clicked element).

If you want to de-activate other elements at the same time:

```
$('.crew-grid').on('click', function () {
    $('.crew-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.crew-item').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help and explanation, I was confused how to target the element, now I'll know, working great !

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
$('.crew-grid').click(function() { 
    $(this).closest('.crew-item').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Document.querySelectorAll()`

```js
var crews = document.querySelectorAll('.crew-item');

if (crews) {

  for (var i = 0; i < crews.length; i++) {
    var grid = crews[i].querySelector('.crew-grid');

    grid.addEventListener('click', toggleActive, false);
  }
}

function toggleActive() {
  var grids = document.querySelectorAll('.crew-item');
  for (var i = 0; i < grids.length; i++) {
    if (grids[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      grids[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.crew-item.active {
  background: #DDD;
}
.crew-grid:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="crew-item active">
  <div class="crew-grid">crew-grid</div>
  <div class="crew-detail">crew-detail</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="crew-item">
  <div class="crew-grid">crew-grid</div>
  <div class="crew-detail">crew-detail</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="crew-item">
  <div class="crew-grid">crew-grid</div>
  <div class="crew-detail">crew-detail</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I was confused how to select the element. Your solution is working great too and prevent me from loading jQuery